# Перебор всех значений связанного графа (С++). Помогите понять в чём проблема

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

Есть граф, элементы которого связаны по схеме:
[image: http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1601/ba/7ee5be3d71d0.png]

Элементы - простые индексы от 0 до 6 включительно.
Хочу перечислить всевозможные пути, например:

```
0, 1
0, 1, 2, 6, 5
0, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4
0, 5, 6, 4
....
```

У меня правильно перебирает только первый путь, но дальше выводятся пути из несвязанных элементов. Почему это происходит? Может кто поможет пофиксить? Уже пару дней бьюсь, не могу понять в чём причина такого поведения.

```
void goElement( std::vector< std::vector< unsigned short > > &relationsArr, unsigned short goElementId, std::vector< unsigned short > visitedIndexesPathArr ) {

    printf( "\nВход в элемент: %i\n", goElementId );

    // Проверяем пути для посещения - если имеются для текущего элемента:
    for ( unsigned short i = 0; i < relationsArr[ goElementId ].size(); i++ ) {

        printf( "\t> Возможный путь: %i для %i элемента", relationsArr[ goElementId ][ i ], goElementId );

        bool notVisited = true; // Проверяем - не посещали ли мы relationsArr[ goElementId ][ i ] (возможный путь для посещения) уже в нашем пути
        for ( unsigned short i1 = 0; notVisited && ( i1 < visitedIndexesPathArr.size() ); i1++ )
            if ( relationsArr[ goElementId ][ i ] == visitedIndexesPathArr[ i1 ] )
                notVisited = false;

        if ( notVisited ) {

            printf( " - не посещён! Посещаем...\n" );

            visitedIndexesPathArr.push_back( relationsArr[ goElementId ][ i ] ); // запоминаем его как посещённый
            goElement( relationsArr, relationsArr[ goElementId ][ i ], visitedIndexesPathArr ); // Посещаем следующий

        } else {

            printf( " - посещён\n" );

        }

    }

    printf( "\t\tВсе посещены, финальный путь: " );
    for ( unsigned short i2 = 0; i2 < visitedIndexesPathArr.size(); i2++ )
        printf( "%i, ", visitedIndexesPathArr[ i2 ] );
    printf( "\n" );

}

int main() {

    std::vector< std::vector< unsigned short > > relationsArr { 
        {1,5,6},
        {0,2,6},
        {1,3,6},
        {2,4,6},
        {3,5,6},
        {0,4,6},
        {0,1,2,3,4,5}
    };

    std::vector< unsigned short > visitedIndexesPathArr;
    visitedIndexesPathArr.push_back( 0 );
    goElement( relationsArr, 0, visitedIndexesPathArr );

}
```

Comment: Ну так посмотрите в отладчике что происходит после вывода первого пути...

Comment: А что именно выводится?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Список `visitedIndexesPathArr` один используется для всех возможных путей, поэтому за его состоянием нужно внимательно следить. Вы изменили его до рекуррентного вызова, но забыли восстановить в исходное состояние после.

```
visitedIndexesPathArr.push_back( relationsArr[ goElementId ][ i ] ); // запоминаем его как посещённый
goElement( relationsArr, relationsArr[ goElementId ][ i ], visitedIndexesPathArr ); // Посещаем следующий
//здесь нужно убрать узел из списка visitedIndexesPathArr
```

Comment: А для чего требуется убирать узел из списка? Ещё не очень понимаю почему у меня один массив для всех путей, я же не по ссылке передаю его, разве получается не у каждого вызова своя копия такого массива списка своих узлов?

Comment: Передача по значению в рекурсии весьма удобна, потому что можно не заботиться о восстановлении состояния, ведь состояние хранится только в контексте конкретного вызова (например на стеке). Но в вашем случае состояние изменяется еще и в цикле. Поэтому первый путь ищется без проблем, а когда делается шаг назад массив `visitedIndexesPathArr` не восстанавливается в исходное состояние. Рекомендую переписать код так, что бы в цикле был только рекуррентный вызов.